# Error installing anaconda

Tags: software-installation, anaconda, conda

I am new in Ubuntu bionic beaver. I have been trying to install Anaconda without success. Apparently, the installation happens, all dependencies are in anaconda folder.
During the installation, when  I command `source ~/.bashrc.` it parses an error

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion : 1461 parse error near'|'
```

See image below:

[image]

First, I have tried to modify the export path in the `.bashrc`  It didn't work. I just leave it as it was.

Later I followed the error, but I am unsure what to  modify there. See image below:

[image]

If anybody has any idea  what should I do, I will appreciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your interactive shell may be `zsh` rather than `bash` - in general, you can't source `bash` resource files into other shells (although their syntax shares a common subset)

Comment: Thank I didnt know that I ll try it again

Comment: **Thanks a lot** It works perfect !